# Kafka consumer in flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am working with kafka and apache flink. I am trying to consume records (which are in avro format) from a kafka topic in apache flink. Below is the piece of code I am trying with.

Using a custom deserialiser to deserialise avro records from the topic.

the Avro schema for the data I am sending to topic "test-topic" is as below.

```
{
  "namespace": "com.example.flink.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "UserInfo",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

The custom deserialiser I am using is as below.

```
public class AvroDeserializationSchema<T> implements DeserializationSchema<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Class<T> avroType;

    private transient DatumReader<T> reader;
    private transient BinaryDecoder decoder;

    public AvroDeserializationSchema(Class<T> avroType) {
        this.avroType = avroType;
    }


    public T deserialize(byte[] message) {
        ensureInitialized();
        try {
            decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(message, decoder);
            T t = reader.read(null, decoder);
            return t;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void ensureInitialized() {
        if (reader == null) {
            if (org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase.class.isAssignableFrom(avroType)) {
                reader = new SpecificDatumReader<T>(avroType);
            } else {
                reader = new ReflectDatumReader<T>(avroType);
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean isEndOfStream(T nextElement) {
        return false;
    }


    public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
        return TypeExtractor.getForClass(avroType);
    }
}
```

And this is how my flink app is written.

```
public class FlinkKafkaApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties kafkaProperties = new Properties();
        kafkaProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaProperties.put("group.id", "test");

        AvroDeserializationSchema<UserInfo> schema = new AvroDeserializationSchema<UserInfo>(UserInfo.class);

        FlinkKafkaConsumer011<UserInfo> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<UserInfo>("test-topic", schema, kafkaProperties);

        DataStreamSource<UserInfo> userStream = env.addSource(consumer);

        userStream.map(new MapFunction<UserInfo, UserInfo>() {

            @Override
            public UserInfo map(UserInfo userInfo) {
                return userInfo;
            }
        }).print();

        env.execute("Test Kafka");

    }
```

I am trying to print the record sent to the the topic which is as below.
`{"name" :"sumit"}`

Output:

The output I am getting is
`{"name":""}`

Can anyone help to figure out what is the issue here and why I am not getting `{"name" : "sumit"}` as output.

Comment: Could you also post the code for `UserInfo`? Does it extend SpecificRecord?

Comment: UserInfo is generated using avro tools plugin.                                           public class UserInfo extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"UserInfo\",\"namespace\":\"com.example.flink.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

Comment: If the class is `SpecificRecord` than it seems strange your code does not work. I can see nothing wrong about it. I would suggest checking if the `deserialize` method works on its own.

Comment: Here is the complete code     https://github.com/sumitnekar/Flink-Examples/blob/master/FlinkKafkaExample/src/main/java/com/example/flink/avro/UserInfo.java

Comment: I tried to debug  deserialize method . Decoder has issue I guess. But i am not able find what is the issue.

Comment: In the code you provided in the generated class the name is of type `int`. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Nope. When i was not successful with String I tried with Int type which eventually din work. It was always giving 0 as the deserialised value.

Comment: If you have any other similar working examples,please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink documentation says :
Flink’s Kafka consumer is called FlinkKafkaConsumer08 (or 09 for Kafka 0.9.0.x versions, etc. or just FlinkKafkaConsumer for Kafka >= 1.0.0 versions). It provides access to one or more Kafka topics.

We do not have to write the custom de-serializer to consume Avro messages from Kafka.

-To read SpecificRecords :

```
DataStreamSource<UserInfo> stream = streamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("test_topic", AvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(UserInfo.class), properties).setStartFromEarliest());
```

To read GenericRecords :

```
Schema schema = Schema.parse("{"namespace": "com.example.flink.avro","type": "record","name": "UserInfo","fields": [{"name": "name", "type": "string"}]}");
DataStreamSource<GenericRecord> stream = streamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("test_topic", AvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(schema), properties).setStartFromEarliest());
```

For more details : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumer

Comment: Thanks @Madhuri Kadam for your answer. Latest versions of Flink has now support for Avro serializers and deserialisers. My issue got resolved.