# Flink KafkaConsumer fail to deserialise a composite avro schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have implemented the solution suggested here: [Kafka consumer in flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191513/kafka-consumer-in-flink),
So my code looks like this:

```
Schema schema = Schema.parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Envelope\" ... etc");
DataStreamSource<GenericRecord> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, AvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(schema), getKafkaCredentials()).setStartFromLatest());
```

But I kept getting the error
`... Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -53`, and
I tried with different topic/schema pairs, and I would always get the same error but with different number (-4 instead of -53 and so on)

What could the problem be? Any suggestion how this issue can be solved?

---

> The only difference I see between my problem and the one in [Kafka consumer in flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191513/kafka-consumer-in-flink) is that my schema is a bit more complex, here is a simplified version of my schema:

```
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "org.example.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "somethingChanged",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "ts",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "long"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "old",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "OldValue",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "int"
              ],
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "last_updated",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ],
              "default": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Value",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "int"
              ],
              "default": null
            },
            {
              "name": "last_updated",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ],
              "default": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

from pom file

```
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.12.1</flink.version>
        <avro.version>1.10.0</avro.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

---

---- Edit : sharing a pom file that actually worked ----

> After implementing the accepted Answer, I had to modify the pom file. But in order to share a useful working pom, I created a new pure Flink app from scratch and bellow is a pom file that worked:

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleFlink2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.12.1</flink.version>
        <avro.version>1.10.0</avro.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <!-- Example:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FlinkKafkaConsumer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AvroDeserializationSchema -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${flink.version}</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- to support for avro generator maven plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.example.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- need to generate pojo from avsc files-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
    <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
    <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- to avoid "No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application" -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: `AvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(schema)` won't work for Confluent-serialized Avro data. You should use `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` + see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849635/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-avro-messageconsuming-message-from-kafka-without

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for pointing this out, should really be added to Flink's official documentation. My problem, beside this, was having mixed versions in the pom file. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: FWIW, you should avoid using log4j 1.2.17 since it has security issues, and use a different log provider like logback or log4j2. You could also upgrade Scala to at least 2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pick a Kafka deserializer format, you need to be aware of how the data was produced.

The Confluent wire format is not the same as plain Avro, and you can expect such out of bounds errors as the parsers are different.

See if `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` class works better

Refer - https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/formats/avro-confluent/

Comment: Beside doing this, I had to fix the versions mix I had in the pom file, and delete the .m2 folder in home directory. 
I then tried with AvroDeserializationSchema again, which did NOT work.
Switching back to ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema worked as you have suggested, most probably because our setup consist of confluent kafka with confluent Schema registry.

Comment: Note: I edited the question to include a working pom file.

Comment: Note: There is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". You can use the Schema Registry with any Kafka cluster, but it is always "_Apache_ Kafka"